# full div width text box and button

Tags: html, css, forms

Hi I would like the form width to be 100%. I would like the text box to extend almost the entire width of the page, and have the small "GO" button directly to the right of the text box, all on the same line (or block).

Right now my text box is only about the width of the text within it ("Enter an address here") Thank you!

CSS

```
#search1{
height: 25px;
padding:5px;
padding-left:11px;
display:inline-block;
background-color:#62564A;
width:100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="search1">
  <form style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;" name="search_form" action="view" method="get"    onsubmit="codeAddress(); return false">
    <input id="address" style="color:#333" value="Enter an address here" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value='';"/>
    <input type="button" value="GO" onclick="codeAddress()"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: `input{ width: 80%; float: left; }` `input[type=button]{ width: 15%; float: left; margin: 0 0 0 5%; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the form with is 100% if you do not change it. If you want the input field to be longer you can use the size attribute.

`<input id="address" size="90" style="color:#333" value="Enter an address here" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value='';"/>`

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TQ9Zs/)

Or you can achieve it through CSS by adding this:

```
#address{
         width:80%;
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks. I should have mentioned I would like to use this on mobile devices as well. The size 90 on smaller screens pushes the GO button below the text box.

Comment: @Andrew you remove the size and add css that uses a relative width. `#address{width:80%}`

Answer (score 0):

css:

```
#search1{
height: 25px;
padding:5px;
padding-left:11px;
display:inline-block;
background-color:#62564A;
width:100%;
}

#search1 button {width:10%;}
#search1 input#address {width:85%;margin-left:5%;}
```

HTML

```
<div id="search1">
  <form style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;" name="search_form" action="view" method="get"    onsubmit="codeAddress(); return false">
    <input id="address" style="color:#333" value="Enter an address here" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value='';"/>
    <button type="button" onclick="codeAddress()"> GO </button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could also do this with a bit of Jquery

CSS:

```
#search1{
    height: 25px;
    padding:5px;
    padding-left:11px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#62564A;
    width:99%;
}
input {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var $ww = $(window).width();
var $input = $('input#address');

$input.width($ww - 90);

$(window).resize(function() {
    $input.width($(window).width() - 90);
});

});
```

I have kept the HTML the same.

include the Jquery library in your `<head>` tag with `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

You may need to tweek the `- 90` to a lower or higher value depending on where you place the form.

Here is a link to the [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Hbn3Q/).